# Spring JPA applicationContext.xml for Google Cloud SQL Postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect to [Google Cloud SQL Postgres](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/) using my Spring 4 application using JPA. Previously, my applicationContext.xml contained:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.avaya.myproject.entity" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hbAdapterBean_pgsql"/>   
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>     
</bean>

<bean id="hbAdapterBean_pgsql" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">  
    <property name="showSql" value="false"></property>  
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"></property>  
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST_}:${DB_PORT_}/${DB_NAME_}"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="${DB_USER_}"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="${DB_PASSWORD_}"></property>  
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I'm struggling to figure out what changes are required in the xml for connecting with Google Cloud SQL Postgres

Answer (score 0):

A common database connection issue in the pom.xml is when there is not a database driver. That works for me because I have MySQL driver in tomcat lib directory and some DataSource connections configured with it. For any database connection related issues, either put the database driver in the container lib or include that in pom.xml dependencies.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Example of applicationContext.xml :

```
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection properties - Driver, URL, user, password -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/TestDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">pankaj</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pankaj123</property>

    <!-- org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! -->
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Mapping with model class containing annotations -->
    <mapping class="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.Employee1"/>
</session-factory>
```

https://www.journaldev.com/2882/hibernate-tutorial-for-beginners